# Window size of tkinter program

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, tkinter

Actually, I thought that the tkinter window is as large as it needs to be. Unfortunately, it's not true for me (I use Lubuntu 16.04).

My question:
Can please someone explain me the examples below? I don't understand tkinter's behaviour.

---

Here an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)

file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar)

menubar.add_cascade(label="This is a very long string because it's just a test . . . ", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", accelerator="Ctrl+N")

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:
Window is not large enough. Why?

[image]

---

Another example (with container Frame):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

container = tk.Frame(root).pack()

menubar = tk.Menu(container)

file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar)

menubar.add_cascade(label="This is a very long string because it's just a test . . . ", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", accelerator="Ctrl+N")

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot: very, very small! You can't really see it. But why is so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows size in Tk is a function of the geometry manager for the window. In the case of your toplevel window the geometry manager is 'wm' which means it is managed by the platform window manager. This asks the application window for a size or sets a default. The menu widget does not provide a size so doesn't affect the geometry calculations. So you get a default toplevel size as you have no widgets managed inside.

In the second case you created a frame with no size dimensions which defaults to a height and width of 0. You pack this which sets the toplevel wdget to use the pack geometry manager for its slaves. This asks the slaves (your frame) how much space they require and sets the master (the toplevel) to a suitable size to contain them. Here that is 0. If you set the width and height of the frame the toplevel will expand to contain that.

Comment: So the problem is that the menubar is irrelevant for the size of the window?

Comment: Yes. The menu is associated with the toplevel. It is not 'inside'. The Tk documentation mentions this (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/toplevel.htm#M11) pointing out on windows the menu is part of the decoration and managed by the window frame. Its a little different on X11 but `winfo_manager` will tell you what is managing each widget.